# Excel Worksheet: Type mismatch error for worksheet added through inputbox

Tags: excel, vba

For a vlookup formula, I am using an inputbox option to select a couple of workbooks (OpenBook_PY and CY) for source data and creating a new workbook (Comp_Book) for main data.
The inputbox function is working successfully however I am facing problem when defining the worksheets in each of the above mentioned book.
Error is type 13 : mismatch error
The problem starts at the 3rd last line, when setting M_Sheet

```
Dim CY_TB As Variant
Dim OpenBook_CY As Workbook
Dim PY_TB As Variant
Dim OpenBook_PY As Workbook
Dim Comp_Book As Workbook
Set Comp_Book = Workbooks.Add
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
CY_TB = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Open Current Period TBC", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
Set OpenBook_CY = Application.Workbooks.Open(CY_TB)

If CY_TB <> False Then
    OpenBook_CY.Activate
    Worksheets(1).Select
    range(range("B6"), range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy Comp_Book.Sheets(1).range("B6")
Dim CY_Rnge As range
End If
'TBC of PY
PY_TB = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Open Prior Period TBC", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
Set OpenBook_PY = Application.Workbooks.Open(PY_TB)
If PY_TB <> False Then
    OpenBook_PY.Activate
    Worksheets(1).Select
End If
Dim M_Sheet As Worksheet, CY_Sheet As Worksheet, PY_Sheet As Worksheet, N_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim M_LR As Long, CY_LR As Long, PY_LR As Long, r As Long
Dim CY_Rng As range, PY_Rng As range

Set M_Sheet = Workbooks(Comp_Book).Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set CY_Sheet = Workbooks(OpenBook_CY).Worksheets("Trial-New")
Set PY_Sheet = Workbooks(OpenBook_PY).Worksheets("Trial-New")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `Workbooks` call:

```
Set M_Sheet = Workbooks(Comp_Book).Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

`Comp_Book` is a `Workbook`, so all you need is:

```
Set M_Sheet = Comp_Book.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

... and similarly for the next two lines.